# Type error: unexpected keyword argument

Tags: django, django-urls, django-1.5

I am receiving the following error message whenever I try to load any item page

`TypeError at /item/103/`

`itemprofile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'item_id'`

The following is my `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
#item urls
    ...
    url(r'^item/(?P<item_id>\d+)/$', views.itemprofile, name='itemprofile')
```

Comment: Can you show your view code? It should be something like `def itemprofile(request, item_id): ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex on URL is completely fine. Add argument `item_id` to your view function and it should work:

```
def itemprofile(request, item_id):
    # View codes
```